# Get values from multiple non-adjacent cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I try to get values (as an array) from multiple non-adjacent cells in Google Sheet.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var arr = ['C1', 'C2', 'C4'];
  var val = ss.getRangeList(arr).getValues();
  Logger.log(val);
}
```

I got the following :

> TypeError: ss.getRangeList(...).getValues is not a function".

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a brief description of you search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 5):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- Unfortunately, there is not method of `getValues` in Class RangeList. I think that this is the reason of your issue.
- In order to retrieve the values from the cells of `['C1', 'C2', 'C4']`, it is required to use the method of `getRanges`. By this, `getValues` can be used.

When these are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var arr = ['C1', 'C2', 'C4'];
  var val = ss.getRangeList(arr).getRanges().map(range => range.getValues());  // Modified
  Logger.log(val);
}
```

- In this case, each element in the array of `val` is 2 dimensional array.

#### Note:

- In your case, each cell is a single cell. So I think that the following script might also be able to be used.

  ```
    var val = ss.getRangeList(arr).getRanges().map(range => range.getValue());
  ```
- Or, in order to retrieve the values from the multiple non-adjacent cells, I created [RangeListApp](https://github.com/tanaikech/RangeListApp) of Google Apps Script library. When this is used, your script is as follows.

  ```
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheetName = ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();
    var arr = ['C1', 'C2', 'C4'];
    var rangeList = arr.map(e => `${sheetName}!${e}`);
    var val = RangeListApp.getSpreadsheet(ss).getRangeList(rangeList).getValues().map(e => e.values);
    Logger.log(val);
  ```

#### References:

- [Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list)
- [getRanges()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#getranges)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Tanaike, your modified script works like charm. Many thanks.